# Contact Form 7 not working in multilingual

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

Contact form 7 shortcode is working in English language.

When i changed to Arabic the form is not working.

Should i do any procedure to move forward?

Please help out !

Comment: It's CF7 Issue. You need to downgrade CF7 version then is works. see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-language-form-not-working/

Comment: CF7 is updated version but my WPML version is 3.3.6

Comment: CF7 developer add "Added custom REST API endpoints for Ajax form  submissions." custom REST API in CF7 so it's create bug in multilingual form

Answer (score 0):

You can get the detailed guidance from this [link](https://wpml.org/documentation/plugins-compatibility/using-contact-form-7-with-wpml/). Here you will get the steps for separating contact form 7 for different languages.

Hope it helps you!